# How to return a value to a label in MIPS64?

Tags: assembly, store, mips64

If I had an immediate value like:

```
.data
sum:  .word  0
```

made some calculations in the code, and wanted to put the result back into "sum" in main memory, how would I do that? I've been going over the manual for the command, but I must not be understanding concepts as well as I should.

Any help for a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Store Word` instruction, `sw`. As usual, you have to use a register for the address, or let the assembler take care of that if it provides such support.

Suppose you want to write`$t0` into `sum`:

```
la $t1, sum
sw $t0, ($t1)
```

or simply `sw $t0, sum` which your assembler will turn into equivalent code.